# I can not understand after" before sneaking..."

Tags: gerund-clauses

“I waited till Zach “inserted himself into our awkward conversation before sneaking inside to thaw my fingers beneath running water.”

Excerpt From
Thirteen Reasons Why
Jay Asher
This material may be protected by copyright.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you are having difficulty with, but perhaps I can explain it in a way that will help.

"till Zach inserted himself into our awkward conversation" tells you how long I waited.

"before sneaking inside to thaw my fingers beneath running water" tells you what it was I was waiting to do.

The structure is "I waited till/until X before doing Y"

Comment: Sneaking inside means?

Comment: Going indoors. _Sneaking_ implies that, once someone else had joined the conversation, it was easier for him to slip away unnoticed.

Comment: Have you looked up "sneak (v)" in a dictionary?